# How to use the NavigationService with frame controls?

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

MVVM Light's Navigation service by default navigates the root frame control when

```
public void NavigateTo(string pageKey);
```

or

```
public virtual void NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter);
```

is called.

However, if the application has more than one Frame control, the NavigationService's usefulness seems to break down, because the current frame is not navigated, but rather the root frame is...

Is the NavigationService intended to be used with an App that doesn't use additional Frame controls?

Comment: You mean the [`INavigationService`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Views/INavigationService.cs)? Couldn't you just have one associated with each frame you want serviced?

Comment: @FilipSkakun - I suppose so...but then would have to deal with keeping them in sync and just seems like it clutters up the app.  Perhaps I need to rethink the layout so that I only need to use one instance of INavigationService...